# how to loop through all buttons on a view inflated in an android service class?

Tags: android, service, view, layout-inflater

I start a service class via  `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />` . During `onCreate()`, I want to make a call to `getWindow()` but where can I get an activity reference?

Can you please help me in finding the reference?

I have used following to inflate a view which is the view that needs an activity reference to `getWindow()`

```
public class myServiceA extends Service {
     public void onCreate() {
       inflater1 = (LayoutInflater) this
            .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

       View1 = inflater1.inflate(R.layout.myview, null);
    }
}
```

I want to loop through all the buttons to change the font size on the view so I need to call getWindow or is there anyway around this?

```
ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) myActivityReference.getWindow()
            .getDecorView();
```

Day 2:
After some lengthy discussion, it seems there is no such activity for my service since it starts by loading the service directly. 
I have to change my question more specifics so that it solves what I want to do.
Below is the code I use to format the font size of buttons on my other activity projects. Now, to do the same on the view inflated on my service class, it will lacks an activity reference. So how to modify the below code so it works for the view in the service class?

```
 public void setButtonFontSize(Activity myActivityReference) {
    ArrayList<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<Button>();
    ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) myActivityReference.getWindow()
            .getDecorView();

        findButtons(viewGroup, buttons, 1);

}

private static void findButtons(ViewGroup viewGroup,
        ArrayList<Button> buttons, int mode) {
    for (int i = 0, N = viewGroup.getChildCount(); i < N; i++) {
        View child = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
        Button childButton;
        if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
            findButtons((ViewGroup) child, buttons, mode);
        } else if (child instanceof Button) {
            buttons.add((Button) child);
            childButton = (Button) child;
            if (mode == 1)
                childButton.setTextSize(12);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry your question is not clear...you want to start service via - What????

Comment: a view that is inflated need an activity reference to call getWindow()

Comment: The above code is in a Fragment or in a Activity?

Comment: The view is inflated inside a service class, code updated

Comment: try ((Activity) getContext()).getWindow()

Comment: I try this (Activity) this.getApplicationContext()  but get error java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity.

Comment: (Activity) getContext()  or  (Activity) this.getContext() , the method is undefined and no run

Comment: see the Day2 details I added

Answer (score 0):

If your desire is to show your view on screen from inside the Service you could use the WindowManager:

```
public class myServiceA extends Service {
    public void onCreate() { 
        Inflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this); 

        View view1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myview, null);

        WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams( WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
        params.x = 0;
        params.y = 100;

        windowManager.addView(view1, params);
    } 
}
```

You must also add the following permission to the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```

Comment: Just add some codes: I want to loop through all the buttons to change the font size on the view so I need to call getWindow or is there anyway around this?

ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) myActivityReference.getWindow()
            .getDecorView();

Comment: Does your application have a running activity when you start your Service? Do you want to change the font for your application's buttons or for buttons on the app currently on screen (other than yours)?

Comment: Yes, what I want is to change the font size of buttons on the view inflated in a service class, which has no activity reference. I updated the question so it specifics solve what I want to do now.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer after changing the specifics of my problem:

```
 ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) View1;
```